# voice recording app

Tags: java, android, mobile

I am making a voice recording android app. The problem is that when I want to pause and continue the record it does not work and the app crashes. 
**This is code** :

```
buttonPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        try {

            recording=false;

            mediaRecorder.pause();

            recording=false;

            buttonRecord.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.record);


            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Recording pause",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }catch (Exception e){



        }
```

and this appears on log 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72Lhm.png)

Comment: my understanding is that once paused the data capturing is stopped and it is written to the memory. so it's non trivial to the append data. i am trying to find an answer too.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the log of the Error, or it's impossible to help you.
The MediaRecorder can be paused ("pause()") and resumed ("resume()"). The only case when Pause() throws an Exception is when it is called before a "start()" or after a "stop()".

Comment: If you're running the App on an Emulator please check this link: https://github.com/nstudio/nativescript-audio/issues/71

Comment: i run app on actual device and emulator and same result

Comment: The "pause()" method was introduced in SDK 24 so your device/emulator doesn't support it. Please check the current SDK_INT version before execute that row.

Comment: Thanks .I read your link and i am understanding the issue . but how most recording app on play store use pause and resume although api older than 24

Comment: Maybe via Reflection, but I'm not sure.